# Populate survey for user agent

Tags: liveagent, chat, livechattranscript

I want to populate a survey(post chat url) for the user as well as I did for the customer, something like a five star rating.
How can I populate a chat for the salesforce user when chat has ended

Comment: are you saying that you have a survey post chat where you have a question which ask you to rate the agent and you want to populate that rating on user record?

Comment: No, I want to the salesforce user to give rating on their experience with the customer

Comment: so I have already add a survey for the customer to rate the employee, I need to do the other way around